# qsort compare function behaviour

Tags: c

everyone. I am trying to change my compare function and almost everything is okay but if i write sth like 0 -5.5 in my infile as an output i recive (after qsort) that -5.5 is greater than 0, and that's not true. Could you check my code and tell me what should i chage?

```
    int compare(const void *str1, const void *str2)
    {
    char *number1, *number2;
    int len1=0, len2=0, dot1=0, dot2=0, value=0;
    int minus1=0, minus2=0;

    number1 = *(char**)str1;
    number2 = *(char**)str2;

    while(*number1=='0') number1++;
    while(*number2=='0') number2++;

    while(*number1 || *number2){
        if(value==0) {value= *number1-*number2;}

        if(*number1){
            if(*number1=='-') number1++;
            if(*number1=='-') minus1=1;
            if(*number1!='.'){
                number1++;
                if(dot1==1) len1++;}

                if(*number1=='.'){
                    number1++;
                    dot1=0;}
        }

        if(*number2){
            if(*number2=='-') number2++;
            if(*number2=='-') minus2=1;
            if(*number2!='.'){
                number2++;
                if(dot2==1) len2++;}

                if(*number2=='.'){
                    number2++;
                    dot2=0;}
        }
    }

    if(minus1>0 && minus2==0){return -1;}
    if(minus1==0 && minus2>0){return 1;}
    if(minus1>0 && minus2>0){
        if(len1>len2) return -1;
        if(len2>len1) return 1;
        return (-value);}
        if(len1>len2) return 1;
        if(len2>len1) return -1;
        return value;
}
```

Comment: ...but if i write sth like 0 -5.5 in my infile...

Comment: Your function compares the `-` in `-5.5` to the NULL at the end of `0` and concludes that its alphabetically greater.  If you want numerically greater, convert the strings to numbers to compare them.

Comment: yes, i thought it's obvious

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `double` into the array treated by `qsort` and `bsearch`.

But if you insist to use `char *`:

```
int compare( const void * l, const void * r ) {
   char * lerr  = NULL;
   char * rerr  = NULL;
   double left  = strtod((const char *)l, &lerr );
   double right = strtod((const char *)l, &rerr );
   return (*lerr||*rerr) ? (int)(l-r) : (int)(left-right);
}
```

[Documentation of strtod](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)